# MVC5 Automatically Scaffold Multiselect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, scaffolding

I normally just scaffold my views and controllers automatically in MVC5, as normally i'm working with simple data driven applications. This is fine untill i wanted to scaffold a view with a multiselect. Can MVC5 generate this? It would save a lot of time in development for us. Or is the issue down to my model?

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("Contact")]
public class Contact : Entity
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SecurityLevel> SecurityLevel{ get; set; }
}

[Table("SecurityLevel")]
public class SecurityLevel: Entity
{
    [Display(Name = "Level")]
    [Required]
    public string Level{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it isn't supported http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2013/09/20/managing-entity-relationships-with-mvc-scaffolding.aspx

Comment: Why!!! This should exist... seriously; nobody thought of making an out of the box everything work package??